# Problem with a Regular Expression in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have a text file with some phrases and some dirt (numbers) that I need to clean.
I wrote the following regular expression in Python 3.8 to do that:

`regex = '[^(\d*:?\d*)](\d{2,8}.*$)|[?).](\d{2,8}.*$)'`

this part `[^(\d*:?\d*)]` is meant to exclude things like `(19)`, `(9:30)` and similar cases that I dont want to eliminate (since it's part of the text and not dirt).

I added the part after the or operator because I noticed that the numbers after the questions mark were still been ignored.

and this is an example of the text that I'm trying to clean:

[image]

The last sentence of the example has all dirt after the question mark, and I wanted to clean it all.

Everything works well except, and as you can see, it grabs part of the text like "?" or ")" and points marks at the end of a sentence.
I couldn't figure it out how to keep those characters and I see no reason why it should work this way. As far as I underestand it, I should not remove those character as the group is restricted to the dirt part of `[?).](\d{2,8}.*$)`.

Comment: Note that you are using a negated character class notation `[^..]` with this `[^(\d*:?\d*)]` which matches any character except for what is listed in the character class.

Comment: This seems to be a common misunderstanding among regexp beginners. `[]` is not used for grouping. `[^pattern]` doesn't mean "don't match `pattern`".

Comment: The fouth bird: yes, that is what I wanted.

Comment: Barmar: I don't understand your comment. [^ ]    - Matches Characters NOT in brackets